# Java regex escaped characters

Tags: java, regex

When matching certain characters (such as line feed), you can use the regex "\\n" or indeed just "\n". For example, the following splits a string into an array of lines:

```
String[] lines = allContent.split("\\r?\\n");
```

But the following works just as well:

```
String[] lines = allContent.split("\r?\n");
```

My question:

Do the above two work in *exactly* the same way, or is there any subtle difference? If the latter, can you give an example case where you get different results?

Or is there a difference only in [possible/theoretical] performance?

Comment: There is no difference. `\\n` matches an LF, `\n` matches an LF.

Comment: If you use COMMENTS mode there should be a difference though.

Comment: @SebastianProske That is true. I mean, given the current regex, there is no difference. If `(?x)` is used, then the whitespace chars should be escaped in the Java regex. Even if they are used in a character class.

Comment: `\\r` means 2 characters in Java: `\ ` and `r`, which in turn interpreted in the RegEx engine as **CR** (Carrige Return) character. On the other hand `\r` means the **CR** in Java, and it is handed over to the RegEx engine as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the current scenario. The usual string escape sequences are formed with the help of a single backslash and then a valid escape char (`"\n"`, `"\r"`, etc.) and *regex escape sequences* are formed with the help of a *literal* backslash (that is, a double backslash in the Java string literal) and a valid regex escape char (`"\\n"`, `"\\d"`, etc.).

`"\n"` (an *escape sequence*) is a literal LF (newline) and `"\\n"` is a regex escape sequence that matches an LF symbol.

`"\r"` (an *escape sequence*) is a literal CR (carriage return) and `"\\r"` is a regex escape sequence that matches an CR symbol.

`"\t"` (an *escape sequence*) is a literal tab symbol and `"\\t"` is a regex escape sequence that matches a tab symbol.

See the list in the [Java regex docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for the supported list of *regex* escapes.

However, if you use a [`Pattern.COMMENTS` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS) (used to introduce comments and format a pattern nicely, making the regex engine ignore all unescaped whitespace in the pattern), you will need to either use `"\\n"` or `"\\\n"` to define a newline (LF) in the Java string literal and `"\\r"` or `"\\\r"` to define a carriage return (CR).

See a [Java test](https://ideone.com/jY9xXf):

```
String s = "\n";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\n", "LF")); // => LF
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\n", "LF")); // => LF
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?x)\\n", "LF")); // => LF
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?x)\\\n", "LF")); // => LF
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?x)\n", "<LF>")); 
// => <LF>
//<LF>
```

Why is the last one producing `<LF>`+newline+`<LF>`? Because `"(?x)\n"` is equal to `""`, an empty pattern, and it matches an empty space before the newline and after it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are different. The Java Compiler has different behavior for `Unicode Escapes` in the `Java Book The Java Language` Specification section 3.3;

> The Java programming language specifies a standard way of transforming
>   a program written in Unicode into ASCII that changes a program into a
>   form that can be processed by ASCII-based tools. The transformation
>   involves converting any Unicode escapes in the source text of the
>   program to ASCII by adding an extra u - for example, \uxxxx becomes
>   \uuxxxx - while simultaneously converting non- ASCII characters in the
>   source text to Unicode escapes containing a single u each.

So how this affect the `/`n vs `//n`  in the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> It is therefore necessary to double backslashes in string literals
>   that represent regular expressions to protect them from interpretation
>   by the Java bytecode compiler.

An a example of the same doc:

> The string literal "\b", for example, matches a single backspace
>   character when interpreted as a regular expression, while "\b"
>   matches a word boundary. The string literal "(hello)" is illegal and
>   leads to a compile-time error; in order to match the string (hello)
>   the string literal "\(hello\)" must be used.

Comment: You are explaining the necessity to use `"\\"` to define a single literal backslash in Java string literals. The OP question is whether `"\n"` and `"\\n"` match the same strings. While the patterns are different, they match the same text. That is why I say *there is no difference in the current scenario*.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct I just wanted the difference between them. In some scenarios have diferent results and in other scenarios have the samem results.