# Why there is no special regular expression construct for backspace character ("\b") like for \\t, \\n, \\r, and \\f in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I’m wondering what is the reason of providing special regular-expression constructs for the following characters:

`\t` - The tab character ('\u0009')

`\n` - The newline (line feed) character ('\u000A')

`\r` - The carriage-return character ('\u000D')

`\f` - The form-feed character ('\u000C')

and, on the other hand, not providing one for backspace character (`\b`).

As it is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45882306/8116173), there is definitely a difference between "`\\n`" compared to "`\n`" or "`\\t`" compared to "`\t`", when `Pattern.COMMENTS` flag is used, but I think it doesn't answer the question, why there is no regular expression construct for backspace character.

Isn't there any possible use case for a regular expression construct for backspace character, not only when `Pattern.COMMENTS` flag is set as active, but maybe in other cases that I don't know yet? Why backspace character is considered as different comparing to other whitespace characters listed above that lead to decision of not providing a regular expression construct for backspace character?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think the duplicate answers the `\\b` part of the question, though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sample answer linked by you, shows the difference between `Matcher.find()` and `String.matches()` which is not the case here I guess. I understand the difference between `\b` and `\\b` (between backspace character and word boundary). As the question that is pointed here as I duplicated it, covers most of my question, I agree, one thing is not covered yet, I guess. Why there is no special construct for backspace character as they are provided for these listed by me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you have a look at current shape of my question as I tried my best to improve its quality and maybe it's an acceptable one right now?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why hasn't been then \\b reserved for equivalent of \b? Word boundary could then have any other, not used for such purposes character, such as \\c, \\h,  etc. I mean, why designers decided to not give any regular expression construct for backspace character, no matter if it's \\b or another, not used sequence? Isn't there any possible use of such construct?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew By saying "why designers..." I just wanted to make clear what I had in mind as it could seem not very clear - I was wondering if there is no possible use case  where regular expression construct equivalent for \b could be helpful and unfortunately it's missing so developers need to think of such a functionality on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Java regex originated from Perl regex, where most shorthand classes have already been defined. Since Perl regex users got accustomed to use `"\\b"` as a word boundary change already accepted and well-known shorthands. `"\\b"` in Perl regex matches a word boundary, and it came with this meaning to Java regex. See this [Java regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> The string literal `"\b"`, for example, matches a single backspace character when interpreted as a regular expression, while `"\\b"` matches a word boundary.

Currently, you can't even make `"\\b"` act as a backspace inside a character set (as in some other languages, e.g. in Python), it is done specifically to avoid human errors when writing patterns. According to the latest specs

> It is an error to use a backslash prior to any alphabetic character that does not denote an escaped construct; these are reserved for future extensions to the regular-expression language.

**If you *have* to use a regex escape for a backspace, use a Unicode regex escape `"\\u0008"`**:

[Java online demo](https://ideone.com/SF76Ci):

```
String s = "word1 and\bword2";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\b")));  // WB
// => [word1,  , and, , word2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\b")));   // BS
// => [word1 and, word2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\b]"))); // BS in a char set
// => [word1 and, word2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\u0008"))); // BS as a Unicode regex escape
// => [word1 and, word2]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("[\\b]")));// WB NOT treated as BS in a char set
// => java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 2
```

Comment: It's understandable that behavior of \\b can't be changed, as it would obviously be a disaster. So if there is a possibility to add additional notation for already existing word boundary notation, I don't really understand why there is no single notation equivalent for backspace character as it is absent for now (I understand that most of these notations are inherited from another language, but if there is a possibility to extend  this set, I don't get it why there isn't one for backspace character created  - like \\c, \\h or anything not reserved yet).

Comment: I don't get how it differs from \\n or \\t, if it could have assigned another letter when 'b' was busy already. Anyway, thank you thank you for your time a d for sheding light on my problem.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal You may want to [submit a suggestion to Java developers](https://bugreport.java.com/).

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I think that there are far more experienced developers than I am and they know what they do ;-) My question was a bit out of curiosity - if there would exist such notation, could it be used in some cases or what developers need to do to provide behavior equivalent to (not existing, in my opinion) regular expression construct corresponding with string \b. I would not be able to explain what would I use this notation for, as it's not my level for now.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal I do not understand why you even want to have a regex escape for a backspace char. You may use `"\\u0008"` to match it. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/SF76Ci).

Comment: And here we reach the main point of the question - as regex escape is needed for other whitespace characters (e.g. \n or \t) for some purposes (Pattern.COMMENTS, as you mentioned in linked answer \n is not equal to \\n in this case), isn't there any possible case in the world (maybe not with Pattern.COMMENTS as it wouldn't have much sense there I think, maybe other case that I don't know) where regex escape for \b would be the only possible way of solving a problem?

Comment: If there is no possible ANY case to use regex escape for backspace, it's understandable it doesn't exist, otherwise I'm curious of possible use.

Comment: Then just use `"\\u0008"`.

Comment: All right, thank you for helping me to understand my issue and I'm sorry if you're disappointed with the quality of question that I asked or of quality of that discussion at all, maybe I need a better understanding of the topic to make it clear what my intentions were. Wish you all the best!