# Split String between lines with regex

Tags: java

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to split the file in the picture and i can't because of the lines...The output i get is all together.What is the right command in regex to split even if there is a new line ?

Comment: Please post the code and file content as text instead of picture. [edit] the question accordingly. See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/4391450)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file using a `Scanner` to get each line.

```
 while(sc.hasNextLine())
```

You append the `StringBuffer` with each line (without a separators).

```
sb.append(sc.nextLine())
```

So at that point, a file with :

```
foo
bar
```

Would give a `StringBuffer` with

```
sb.toString(); //foobar
```

So there is not line separator left... Instead, do that with the `Scanner`.

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s):
    sb.append(s);
}
```

*Last thing, please close every `Scanner` you open with `sc.close()` when you are done with them (that's a good practice to have).*

EDIT:

If you want to keep that logic, simply append with a line separator after each lines:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append("\n");
}
```

That way, you will always have a line separator and the split will work

Quick example of what this would look like :

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("foo").append("\n")
  .append("bar").append("\n"); //fake "file reading"

String[] result = sb.toString().split("\n");
for(String s : result){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

> foo
>   bar

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
protasi[] = string.split("\\r?\\n");
```

`split("\n")` won't work because you need to provide a back-slash for `\n` which becomes `\\n`. I'd also added `\\r` which is what we should use for newline/carriage return.

Comment: When the String is given as a variable it works but if i read it from a text file it doesn't

Comment: Please explain why this solution should be valid in the answer. This would help OP to understand his mistake and don't do it again.

Comment: PS: check [Java regex escaped characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45882306/4391450).

Comment: axel your answer was helpful. that's what i did! thanks